# Fetch height of an element inside a not-active tab on document ready?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a tabs navbar as follows-

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">TAB1</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab"><p>TAB2<p></div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">TAB3</div>
</div>
```

I want to fetch the height of the TAB2 text as soon as I load the document.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
 console.log($(p).css('height')); 
});
```

This returns me 0px. However, if I try to fetch it from a button within the tab, it gives the result as the text is already rendered by then.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: `$('p').parent().innerHeight()`?

Comment: the `p` height will be same as its `div#myTabContent` - correct ?

Comment: I guess `p` is `<p>TAB2<p>` in second tab. "I want to fetch the height of the TAB2 text"

Comment: @AlwaysHelping , yes. This is just a sample though. If I have more elements and I want to get height of some particular element, then how can I fetch it? I can fetch any other style that has been already set in the CSS but not height , width etc. Something about the rendering cycle maybe...idk. Any solution?

Comment: @AbbasEbadian I just want the height of <p> not the entire div. In real scenario, I have more elements on the page.

Comment: @ItykaBandta yes - it possible - are you just wanting to store height or show somewhere once the page loads only for `p` element ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Yes, I want to apply a condition after fetching the height. So for example, If I have p tag, h1 tag, img etc I would like to fetch the height of say img or p tag or any element and then apply some condition.

Comment: I used a trick to get its height.Cloned its parent, added some classes to make it invisible and attached to body , get height of target element (p in this example) and remove cloned element. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vm8jdsox/2/)

Comment: @AbbasEbadian Idk how it will work with the actual code. I will try this. Thanks !

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Any idea?

Comment: @ItykaBandta See my detailed answer that should cover everything you want height / width` OR `x/y` etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this but you have `show` the `p` **OR** other elements you want to get `height` of in DOM - show as in only to show get the height and then hide again. You will not even notice about `show` and `hide`.

Since the `height` method only `works` on elements that are `available` on the page your `p` or other `divs` are hidden by `default`

I have using pure `JavaScript` which is `jQuery` anyways. You can use `forEach` to loop through all the elements first and add show class and then remove class once we have fetched the `height`.

To get the actual `height / width` OR `x/y` etc etc you can this one function [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) which will return everything you want.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  let rect = document.querySelectorAll('p')
  rect.forEach(function(x) {
    x.parentElement.classList.add('show', 'active') //add active class
    let elem = document.querySelector('p').getBoundingClientRect() //get all the `p` height
    console.log(elem.height) //get height 24
    console.log(elem) //the whole object i.e height / width` OR `x/y`
  })
  rect.forEach(function(x) {
    x.parentElement.classList.remove('show', 'active') //remove active class
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">TAB1</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
    <p>TAB2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
    TAB3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a ton mate ! This is such a neat solution ! I tried it with a table with three rows that have height 55px,45px,45px respectively. When I load the page, it gives the right result. Then I refresh 3-4 times and the values change for some reason. Again, I refresh and I get the right result. I read that window event listeners are not very consistent and can can vary with browsers. Am I correct ?
Nevertheless, it's a great solution. Thanks !

Comment: @ItykaBandta No problem happy to help :) You can use `document.ready function` as well its the same thing as `window.DOMContentLoaded` and this `DOMContentLoaded` l works all on browsers [here is compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event#Browser_compatibility) - for variation in results on page refresh it actually depend on how the content of is being loaded is ready is ready for JS to give you results - if its loaded via ajax or something like that. But you should get the right values according to specs set in CSS.

Comment: Yes. I tried with that as well. Though still toggling between right and wrong values ! :D But this solution will work for me ! & I am still wondering about "height method only works on elements that are available on the page " - if it can fetch other properties, that means the DOM elements are available. (but not yet rendered, correct ?) I am a little unclear about the chronology.

Comment: @ItykaBandta Yes that is correct as the height can dynamic depending on page size unless it set to static for some elements you are looking for. So yeah it will be only shown in `rect` one the element become visible or shown on the page.